ERPNext on google cloud platform
Wish to have a help from your guys. I am installing frappe/bench on an Ubuntu virtual machine on Google cloud platform. I followed the instructions on GitHub with an easy installation.
https://github.com/frappe/bench
After completing the installation I tested using the command docker ps and the results were that the containers were running.
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                                                      NAMES
ae449a7742d3   frappe/erpnext:v15.27.1   "nginx-entrypoint.sh"    26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes                                                                                        frappe-frontend-1
5f4f4f67e4ec   frappe/erpnext:v15.27.1   "/home/frappe/frappe…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes                                                                                        frappe-backend-1
033c0bc3155e   frappe/erpnext:v15.27.1   "bench worker --queu…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes                                                                                        frappe-queue-short-1
b4fbd5babd1d   frappe/erpnext:v15.27.1   "bench schedule"         26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes                                                                                        frappe-scheduler-1
543024d2e950   frappe/erpnext:v15.27.1   "node /home/frappe/f…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes                                                                                        frappe-websocket-1
efaf3ac17f61   frappe/erpnext:v15.27.1   "bench worker --queu…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes                                                                                        frappe-queue-long-1
0b1f75f9de75   mariadb:10.6              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes (healthy)   3306/tcp                                                                   frappe-db-1
d1103a4689ab   redis:6.2-alpine          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes             6379/tcp                                                                   frappe-redis-cache-1
092fd582f9e8   traefik:2.5               "/entrypoint.sh --pr…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes             0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   frappe-proxy-1

However after that I can't see any content when accessing "http://ip_server". The error given is "404 page not found" This means I have access to the server, but there is no content.
I have tried several docker configuration methods but all of them do not work. I don't know clearly what the main problem is? Why? I need guidance
